# Rails 4: How to store array of custom-class objects as an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json, store

I am trying to store array of custom Cluster class objects as an attribute using [Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html)

The problem now is that when the JSON encoder is passed an `array` of objects like:

```
 [
   4.25, 136.25: 4 points, quant: 285.06307738701975,
   47.5, 905.0: 2 points, quant: 11.180339887498949
 ]
```

This stores as:

```
[{"center"=>{"coords"=>{"x"=>5.5, "y"=>207.5}},
  "points"=>
   [{"coords"=>{"x"=>6.0, "y"=>195.0}, "z"=>8},
    {"coords"=>{"x"=>5.0, "y"=>220.0}, "z"=>9}],
  "moved"=>false},
 {"center"=>{"coords"=>{"x"=>3.0, "y"=>65.0}},
  "points"=>
   [{"coords"=>{"x"=>4.0, "y"=>70.0}, "z"=>12},
    {"coords"=>{"x"=>2.0, "y"=>60.0}, "z"=>13}],
  "moved"=>false},
 {"center"=>{"coords"=>{"x"=>47.5, "y"=>905.0}},
  "points"=>
   [{"coords"=>{"x"=>50.0, "y"=>900.0}, "z"=>10},
    {"coords"=>{"x"=>45.0, "y"=>910.0}, "z"=>11}],
  "moved"=>false}]
```

So, instead of Cluster class I get `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` for each array element. If I do not use json it falls down at all. Ruby cannot read `4.25, 136.25: 4 points, quant: 285.06307738701975,` as an object from attribute `hash`.

Do I have other options to store that non-standard objects as array in attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Got another solution for this - Instead of using ActiveRecord::Store with json I made stuff working with [serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) method:

```
serialize :cluster_array, Array
```

so now I am able to save array of Cluster objects as attribute.